# Java JButton below another JButton

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton

I have three main buttons , "Internet" , "Contract" and "CardContract" .
If I click "Internet" then "button1" shows
If I click "Contract" then "button2" shows
and If I click "CardContract" then "button3" shows
The problem is that only the first button that I click each time is visible.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton btnNewButton_0 = new JButton("CardContract");
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Conctract");
JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Internet");

public Constructor() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 568, 409);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

    panel_2.add(btnNewButton_0);
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(this);

    panel_2.add(btnNewButton_1);
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(this);

    panel_2.add(btnNewButton_2);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(this);
}

if (e.getSource() == btnNewButton_0){
                        JButton Button_5 = new JButton("Giga Pro Internet");
                        Button_5.setBounds(72, 79, 139, 23);
                        panel.add(Button_5);     

                }else if(e.getSource() == btnNewButton_1){

                        JButton Button_6 = new JButton("For all");
                        Button_6.setBounds(72, 79, 139, 23);
                        panel.add(Button_6);

                }else if(e.getSource() == btnNewButton_2){

                        JButton Button_6 = new JButton("Foititiko");
                        Button_6.setBounds(72, 79, 139, 23);
                        panel.add(Button_6);


                    }
                }
```

If the button_5 button is Visible , if I click "Contract" the button_6 will be created below the button_5 for some reason.

Comment: Stop setting the bounds of your components, and use a layout manager. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: Using Box [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box) is one possible solution